# How to get back the "Windows can't open this file" dialog box?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, dialog

The other day by mistake I associated my pdf files to Sumatra as the default pdf reader and I wanted to undo this action. What I did was to follow the steps given already [on this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/904188/how-can-i-unassociate-a-file-type-from-a-program-without-a-registry-edit) using DefaultProgramsEditor however, now each time I try to access the file I get the error which it can be seen below.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

My windows 7 verstion is on spanish but it can be read the classic dialog box which says

```
This file has not associated a program to execute this      action. 
Install the program which corresponds or if you have it installed, 
create an association on control panel from default programs.
```

While I can do what Windows is telling me to do, it isn't exactly what I wanted.

In fact I wanted to bring back this dialog box from below

[image: Sketch of the second dialog box]

which it was what I originally got each time when I opened pdf files after uninstalling foxit reader.

There it reads,

```
To open this file it must be indicated on Windows which programs
must be desired to used for such purpose. Windows can connect to 
the internet to search automatically or it can be selected manually 
from a list of programs on this computer.
```

I managed to open this window as I have a file which let me to open this dialog box, but I wanted this dialog box to appear each time I opened my pdf files because it let me to quickly choose which pdf program I could use, but now I can't.

[image: Sketch of the third dialog box]

How can I bring back this dialog box along with this other?

Please I tried all sorts of tricks in my belt but none had brought back the requested features.

I even reinstalled Adobe pdf reader and uninstalled it but it did not solved the issue. Anyone can help me on this please?

Comment: right click on the file ans select "open with", then set the default program.

Comment: @Moab This action would not resolve my problem because I would get back to what I initially had problems with and that was how to dissociate a program assigned to a particular file. In this case what I need is to get back the windows cant open this file thus by selecting the option let me choose the program I would select the desired program. But it was not set default.